# Bulk Transfer of Subfolders into Parent Folders

Tags: powershell, cmd, batch-processing, directory, subdirectory

I have a problem that I cannot seem to find any solution to online. I am trying to restructure some data structures that I ended up with after exporting some data from my old database service.

The export left me with a bunch of client folders in the format of [Client Name] -> Archive -> Archive -> [Client Files/Subfolders]. What I would like to end up with is [Client Name] -> [Client Files/Subfolders], removing the two redundant "Archive" folders in between.

Many people have suggested to me that I simply cut and paste the files from the subfolder to the client root directory, however with hundreds of client folders this would be a very long task to do. Would there be any batch cmd command or powershell command I could use to work through these folders and restructure them? Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: Please copy and paste the code you are trying into the question and it is likely that someone will have a suggestion. If you need to hire a programmer, SO is not the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three built-in PoSH cmdlets are there for exactly these purposes.

Get-ChildItem (aka gci, dir and ls)

```
(Get-Command -Name Get-ChildItem).Parameters.Keys
Get-Help -Name Get-ChildItem -Full
Get-Help -Name Get-ChildItem -Examples
```

Move-Item (aka mi, move, and mv)

```
(Get-Command -Name Move-Item).Parameters.Keys
Get-Help -Name Move-Item -Full
Get-Help -Name Move-Item -Examples
```

Remove-Item (aka del, erase, rd, ri, rm, rmdir)

```
(Get-Command -Name Remove-Item).Parameters.Keys
Get-Help -Name Remove-Item -Full
Get-Help -Name Remove-Item -Examples
```

See details here:
Files and Folders in Windows PowerShell

We’ll start out by telling you that everything you learned last month about manipulating files and folders with WMI will work in Windows PowerShell. PowerShell has a cmdlet called Get-WMIObject that allows you to access all the classes, methods and properties of WMI. Just like with VBScript, WMI is the only way to work with files and folders remotely in Windows PowerShell. We’re not going to get into working with WMI in Windows PowerShell in this article, but we’re going to show you the PowerShell way to work with files and folders.
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176988.aspx

As for this...
"removing the two redundant "Archive" folders in between."

If there is nothing in these folders of value, then the above Remove-Item should be all you need. Otherwise you move all files from the to wherever, then remove the folders.

Or just use robocopy

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145(v=ws.11).aspx
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx

Robocopy (Robust File Copy) is a command-line file copy utility that comes with Windows Vista / Windows 2008 or newer. Until Vista, Robocopy was a part of Windows Resource Kit Tools as a free download (http://aka.ms/robocopydownload Jump ). Unlike normal copy commands, Robocopy is designed for reliable copy or mirroring while maintaining the permissions, attributes, owner information, timestamps and properties of the objects copied.